# How to turn off alarmClock

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

Hello I was looking on some questions about how to turn off alarm clock in my app but nothing helped me. I have two buttons on and off and alarm can normally start but i cant turn it off.

My AlarmActivity

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

AlarmManager alarmManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private TimePicker alarmTimePicker;
private static AlarmActivity inst;
private TextView alarmTextView;
Button on, off;

public static AlarmActivity instance() {
    return inst;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);
    alarmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmText);
    Button on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zapni);
    Button off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vypni);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


    on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm On");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);


        }

    });

    off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent,0);
            AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            aManager.cancel(pIntent);

            Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");

        }

    });


}
```

My AlarmReciever Class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    AlarmActivity inst = AlarmActivity.instance();
    inst.setAlarmText("Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!");


    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null) {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();


    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            AlarmService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

My AlarmService Class

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
private NotificationManager alarmNotificationManager;

public AlarmService() {
    super("AlarmService");
}

@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    sendNotification("Wake Up! Wake Up!");
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Alarm")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");
}
```

}

There is something wrong in my opinion

```
off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent,0);
        AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        aManager.cancel(pIntent);

        Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA); 
    AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    aManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);`  I have used this code without this. because it was throwing out some error but still nothing

Comment: When I write there this.getApplicationContext() it throws this error      
      Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext()'                                           But when i delete this. it works but alarm still dont want to turn off

Comment: You can use Activity's Context.  I think you have not much idea about Context. search about application and activity's contexts.

Comment: I have  read something about it but can be there getApplicationContext() ? i dont know what to do because i cant turn off this alarm...

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1253, intent,0);
AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
aManager.cancel(pIntent);
stopService(new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class));
```

you tray like that its may be help other wise refer [this.](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock)

Comment: alarm is still playing but i cant turn it off